# remove all results of join if one record of join is not matched

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two table.

```
A    
ID   NAME
--------------
1    A


B
USER_ID  role
--------------
1         ADMIN
1         USER
1         ROLE2
```

IF  i use `A LEFT JOIN B where role!='admin'` i get 2 results.
but what if i want no results for user 1 because one record of user is not matched?

Comment: What results do you want?  2 results - 2 results = no results.  Just don't run any queries.

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: sorry, i want no result because user id 1 has admin role

Comment: Sounds like you want to find users who AREN'T admins, e.g. user 2?

Comment: I'm thinking he more wants users who do have roles but aren't admins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a subquery.

```
 Select * from A 
        where ID not in (select USER_ID from B where role = 'ADMIN')
```

If you want only results where there is a role in B, you can add an inner join:

```
 Select * from A
       Inner join B on A.ID = B.User_ID
       where A.ID not in (select B2.USER_ID from B B2 where B2.role = 'ADMIN')
```

Which will restrict the results to those that have a match in table B and those without an ADMIN role.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM
  A INNER JOIN B
  ON A.ID = B.USER_ID
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B AS b2 WHERE b2.USER_ID = A.ID AND b2.ROLE = 'ADMIN')
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is actually unclear. Based on what I understand from the data,

If the user ID ( in his case '1' ) is an admin he does not want to return any records with user id as '1'. So lets extend this table a bit.

```html
A    
ID   NAME
--------------
1    A


B
USER_ID  role
--------------
1         ADMIN
1         USER
1         ROLE2
2         NOTADMIN
2         ROLE3
```

You can use the below query to filter out records that you don't want.

```css
select X.id, Y.id, Y.Role from table_A as Y
Left Join 
( select B.id, B.Role from table_B as B join ( select id from table_B where Role = 'admin' ) as A on A.id != B.id ) as X 
on (x.id = Y.id)
```

Then you get only :

2         NOTADMIN

2         ROLE3

Hope this helps..